# Strip word from mysql value

Tags: php, mysql, select

Looking to run a select query to filter products by size, however the column `Product_Size` has characters after the number, for example 'inches'. I have tried the below but it brings back no results.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` where Product_size BETWEEN '2 inches' AND '4.9 inches'
```

How do I strip the word 'inches' from the query?

Comment: What is the data type of the column `Product_size`?

Comment: @forpas - varchar(255)

Comment: Any comparison between strings is always alphabetical. Post sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace()`

```
  SELECT * FROM products 
  where Category_List =1 and Category_List_2=7 and 
  Designed_For_Who LIKE '%%' and (RRP between '0' and '100000') and 
  Product_size BETWEEN cast(replace('2 inches',' inches','') as int) AND 
  cast(replace('4.9 inches',' inches','') as int) 
  ORDER BY Name ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I add this into my query (below) I get an error?

`SELECT * FROM products where Category_List =1 and Category_List_2=7 and Designed_For_Who LIKE '%%' and  (RRP between '0' and '100000') and Product_size BETWEEN cast(replace('2 inches',' inches','') as int) AND cast(replace('4.9 inches',' inches','') as int ORDER BY Name  ASC

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY Name  ASC LIMIT 0, 25'

Comment: @Designer, You've missed a bracket - SELECT * FROM products where Category_List =1 and Category_List_2=7 and Designed_For_Who LIKE '%%' and (RRP between '0' and '100000') and Product_size BETWEEN cast(replace('2 inches',' inches','') as int) AND cast(replace('4.9 inches',' inches','') as int) ORDER BY Name ASC

Answer (score 1):

You must convert the strings to numeric values.
For your case this conversion can be done implicitly by adding `0`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products` 
WHERE 
  Product_size LIKE '%inches'
  AND
  Product_size + 0 BETWEEN '2 inches' + 0 AND '4.9 inches' + 0
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tdPbpZWku95KUBb8a1wdKC/1).